# FFMPEG performance with HW acceleration

Tags: ffmpeg, graphics-card, cpu, performance

I'm doing some video conversions with FFMPEG and have a question about hardware acceleration.

First I converted a video on my laptop with an i7 processor. After some tips I maximized the speed using Intel's QuickSync which is a huge performance boost. My video is a 1080p video shot with a gopro camera. I'm using the latest Windows build downloaded from gyan.dev

Here is my command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y hwaccel qsv -i MY_VIDEO.mp4 -codec:v h264_qsv -preset slow -b:v 8000000 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -c:a copy -movflags faststart CONVERTED.mp4
```

That processes the video with a speet at about 160fps, which is great comparing to the software encoder.

Now I have a gaming computer - with an i7 10700F Comet Lake processor and a **NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070** graphics card. I thought that things will speed up massively. Its the same command, only the decoder and encoder are changed.

```
ffmpeg.exe -y hwaccel cuda -i MY_VIDEO.mp4 -codec:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -b:v 8000000 -bf 2 -flags +cgop -c:a copy -movflags faststart CONVERTED.mp4
```

Unfortunately, the speed is about 180fps. Am I missing something, or is that the best ffmpeg can do with this graphics card? It is almost the same speed as my laptop.

Answer (score 3):

The hardware encoder on your CPU and your GPU will be aiming at specific performance levels.

The performance of a hardware encoding block is dependent of the actual hardware block and less on the general card performance.

A 3070 may absolutely trounce integrated graphics for 3D rendering, but unless the hardware encoder is massively more powerful as well then getting similar performance is not entirely surprising. The hardware encoders will be aiming at being "more than capable of" (for example) 4K60 but how much further is down to the block designed by each manufacturer.  Going that much far above and beyond will reach limits of cost vs benefit.

Modern hardware encoders are specific areas of silicon beside your GPU cores that are dedicated to video encoding, and will be almost completely unaffected by the speed or quantity of of cores on your GPU.

There used to be encoders that used the GPU computational cores, but they could severely hamper game or system performance as they took resource from other things that may need them. They also needed to be programmed specifically for each manufacturer of graphics card, AMD, Intel and Nvidia and so it fell to the manufacturers. They in turn fell back to doing it in hardware (silicon) as it meant copy-pasting a block rather than rewriting software for each performance level and generation and trying to not use "too much" resource that would hurt the performance of their primary use of playing games.

The problem then becomes that those hardware blocks tend to display somewhat similar performance as they are "good enough" for most tasks. What you may see though is that for any given bitrate one hardware encoder produces a different quality output.